# ajax get request timeout not triggering error handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, timeout

I'm trying to make an ajax call to a function that reads and show data from a table but if the process is taking too long, the ajax call should stop and show an error message. I've tried using the `timeout` parameter on the ajax function but the error handler doesn't get triggered; but instead it calls the success event handler..

JS:

```
var start_time = new Date().getTime();
var req_time, max_time;
max_time = 100;

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'mypage/myfunction',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  timeout: max_time,
  success: function(res) {
    req_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time; // 2106 miliseconds
    console.log('success!', res, req_time);
  },
  error: function(err, txtStatus) {
    console.log('error!', err, txtStatus); // doesn't get triggered even though req_time > max_time
  },
  complete: function() {
    req_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time; // 2107 miliseconds
    console.log('complete', req_time);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that timeout takes in milliseconds. So if you would like to execute the error handler, please assign max_value to 2000 nearby!

**jQuery <= 1.7.2**

```
var start_time = new Date().getTime();
var req_time, max_time;
max_time = 2000; // Please update the max_time 

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'mypage/myfunction',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  timeout: max_time,
  success: function(res) {
    req_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time; // 2106 miliseconds
    console.log('success!', res, req_time);
  },
  error: function(err, txtStatus) {
    console.log('error!', err, txtStatus); // doesn't get triggered even though req_time > max_time
    if(textStatus === 'timeout')
    {     
         alert('Failed from timeout');         
        //do something. Try again perhaps?
    }
  },
  complete: function() {
    req_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time; // 2107 miliseconds
    console.log('complete', req_time);
  }
});
```

**jQuery 1.8+**

```
var start_time = new Date().getTime();
var req_time, max_time;
max_time = 2000; // Please update the max_time 
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'mypage/myfunction',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  timeout: max_time,
 }).done(function(){
     //do something
 }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
     if(textStatus === 'timeout')
     {     
        alert('Failed from timeout'); 
        //do something. Try again perhaps?
     }
 });​
```

Comment: yes I know that `timeout` is in miliseconds.. I set max_time 100 only to make sure that it's smaller than req_time. is jquery unable to do it if the value is too small?

Comment: btw, I edited the value into 2000 but it still won't trigger the error() handler..

Comment: @dapidmini Yes, if the value is too small then it will be passed. Because it continues to execute the javascript. Have you tried with different values?